# Need to Select Value of Grandparent's Sibling with a Specific Attribute in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

With the following XML I need to select the home address if it exists, and the work address if it does not.  So I am trying to find the syntax to select the value of wd:Address_Line_Data[@wd:Descriptor="Address_Line_1"] from the starting point of wd:Address_Line_Data/wd:Usage/wd:Type_Data/wd:Type_Reference/@wd:Descriptor="Home"

Here is the XML:

```
                  <wd:Contact_Data>
                    <wd:Address_Data>
                       <wd:Address_Line_Data  wd:Descriptor="Address Line 1">
                       <wd:Usage_Data>
                          <wd:Type_Data>
                             <wd:Type_Reference wd:Descriptor="Work">
                             </wd:Type_Reference>
                          </wd:Type_Data>
                       </wd:Usage_Data>
                    </wd:Address_Data>
                    <wd:Address_Data>
                       <wd:Usage_Data>
                          <wd:Type_Data>
                             <wd:Type_Reference wd:Descriptor="Home">
                             </wd:Type_Reference>
                          </wd:Type_Data>
                       </wd:Usage_Data>
                    </wd:Address_Data>
                 </wd:Contact_Data>
```

I am very new to XSTL, and I have tried the following three expressions, all of which do absolutely nothing.  I am working with xml 1.0.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

```
    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Worker_Data/wd:Personal_Data/wd:Contact_Data/wd:Address_Data/wd:Usage_Data/wd:Type_Data/wd:Type_Reference[@wd:Descriptor='Home']/ancestor::wd:Address_Data/wd:Address_Line_Data[@wd:Descriptor='Address_Line_1']"/>     

<xsl:value-of select="wd:Worker_Data/wd:Personal_Data/wd:Contact_Data/wd:Address_Data/wd:Usage_Data/wd:Type_Data/wd:Type_Reference[@wd:Descriptor='Home'][ancestor::wd:Address_Data[wd:Address_Line_Data[@wd:Descriptor='Address_Line_1']]]"/>        

<xsl:value-of select="wd:Worker_Data/wd:Personal_Data/wd:Contact_Data/wd:Address_Data/wd:Usage_Data/wd:Type_Data/wd:Type_Reference[@wd:Descriptor='Home']/ancestor::wd:Usage_Data/preceding-sibling::wd:Address_Line_Data[@wd:Descriptor='Address_Line_1']"/>
```

Comment: The provided text that resembles XML isn't actually a well-formed XML document -- there are structural malformities. Please, edit the question and correct.

Answer (score 0):

**In XPath 1.0 one can select using `expr1` if a given condition `$cond` is `true()` and `expr2` otherwise using this single XPath expression**:

```
(expr1)[$cond] | (expr2)[not($cond)]
```

This can be applied to your case. The only difficulty is that you haven't provided a well-formed XML document, nor have you specified the exact condition and the exact (sets of) nodes that must be selected when `$cond` or when `not($cond)`